# Block column reorder to specific target display index in data grid xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridcolumn, datagridcolumnheader

I have an XAML `DataGrid` which has 10 columns. I am able to reorder the column but I want to block reordering columns within group.

For example, a user can reorder the column no 9 to column no 5 (which is possible now) but column no 9 should not allow to drag less than column no 4.

I want to restrict the column reordering based on display index.

I've tried to use `ColumnReordering` event but wasn't able to find drop location index of drag column so I can block it.

##### xaml.cs file

```cs
grid.ColumnReordering += Grid_ColumnReordering;

private void Grid_ColumnReordering(object sender, DataGridColumnReorderingEventArgs e) 
{ 
    object DropLocationIndicator = e.DropLocationIndicator; 
    object Dragindicator = e.DragIndicator; 
    // Drag column
     var column = e.Column;

     //find target display index and block it
     if (targetdisplayindex > 4)
     {
         e.Cancel = false;
     }
     else
     {
        e.Cancel = true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ColumnReordering` event is raised before the target display index is known. You could use it to store the original column index and then handle the `ColumnDisplayIndexChanged` to move the column back based on your logic. Something like this:

```
private int _displayIndex;

private void OnColumnReordering(object sender, DataGridColumnReorderingEventArgs e)
{
    _displayIndex = e.Column.DisplayIndex;
}

private void OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    int newIndex = e.Column.DisplayIndex;
    int oldIndex = _displayIndex;

    // if (some condition...)
    // switch back:
    dataGrid.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged -= OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged;
    e.Column.DisplayIndex = oldIndex;
    dataGrid.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged += OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged;
}
```